# How to add a struct field from a schema definition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a nice way in scala to achieve the following? My current code looks like this,

```
val secConfig: ArrayType = ArrayType(
StructType(
   StructField("rand55", StringType, nullable = true),
   StructField("rand2", DoubleType, nullable = true),
   StructField("rand22", LongType, nullable = true),
   StructField("rand31", DoubleType, nullable = true),
   .....
   StructField("rand24", DoubleType, nullable = true),
)
)
val fieldSchema: StructField = StructField("field_name", secConfig, nullable = true)


val newDf = df.withColumn("new_col",
array(
  struct(
     lit(null).cast(StringType).as("rand55"),
     lit(null).cast(DoubleType).as("rand2"),
     lit(null).cast(Longype).as("rand22"),
     lit(null).cast(DoubleType).as("rand314"),
     ...
     lit(null).cast(DoubleType).as("rand24"),
)))
```

I just want to add nulls, typecast and name the fields from the schema. Is there a nice way in scala to avoid hardcoding redundancy for several columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a loop to do the job

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, StringType, DoubleType}

// Creating a bogus dataframe in order to follow your example
val df = Seq((1,2),(11,22)).toDF("One", "Two")

val newDf = df.withColumn("new_col",
array(
  struct( (0 to 24).map(i => {
     lit(null).cast(StringType).as(s"f$i")
  }):_*
  )))

newDf.printSchema
```

Which returns:

```
root
 |-- One: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Two: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- new_col: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- f20: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- f21: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- f22: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- f23: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- f24: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks Lars for the answer. But please note that the column names are just a representation and the real world column names are random. I have now updated the question.

Comment: But, I get the gist anyways. Upvoting your answer

Comment: Instead of having iteration on dataframe for withColumn, the same can be done while creating the secConfig object and then applying it to dataframe which will automatically add null values. In this way, it can be more efficient.